# Format for storing hierarchical object data for both human&programmatic post-processing?

Tags: python, database, json, pickle

I would like to store multiple instances (different result sets) of relatively small amounts (say a few 1kB per record) of structured data from python-based scripts into external file, which should be both human-accessible and compter-accessible.

The type of data is hierarchical dictionary (objects and properties, which can be primitive types (numbers, strings, lists) or nested objects). Structure of records can vary slightly, and the structure should not need to be defined in advance.

The file would be mostly-reading, rarely adding new records (only from computation code), and never modifying existing records.

I can already pickle the data or export them to JSON, but I would like to add integration with some more user-oriented interfaces -- notably spreadsheets (libreoffice/gnumeric); the user should be able to use his tool to say something like:

```
take all computations from yesterday and for each computation, plot point beta as function of foo.alpha if foo.alpha>.15
```

Obviously, this is trivial to write in python+matplotlib, but I am exporing ways to extend the usage to non-pythonistas.

Comment: Is your question about the data format or the query/computation language?  JSON is a good choice for the data format, but no matter what data format you use, you can't force LibreOffice to allow manipulation via the type of query language you suggest.

Comment: I am quite flexible in producing the data (fluent in python/c++/whatever is needed), but I would like the format match one supported by those more user-friendly apps. I know e.g. LibreOffice supports database backends, but relational databases are poor match for data without strict structure. The kind of query language is a choice as well, as long as a computer-experienced person (with background in programming) can use it. So: I am looking for both format & query language which match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A standard notation to target contents inside structured data formats (XML, JSON)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783602/a-standard-notation-to-target-contents-inside-structured-data-formats-xml-json)