# A standard notation to target contents inside structured data formats (XML, JSON)?

Tags: xml, json, pointers, xpath, data-structures

Here's the problem:
I'm in a Web environment and I have data expressed in some structured format, say XML or JSON.
I want to target elements inside these representations.

Here's an example:

The XML representation of a zoo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<zoo>
    <dog>Joe</dog>
    <cat>Alfred</cat>
    <mouse>Ricky</mouse>
</zoo>
```

The JSON representation of the same zoo:

```
{
  "zoo": {
    "dog": "Joe",
    "cat": "Alfred",
    "mouse": "Ricky"
  }
}
```

Say, I'd like to hit the dog's name.

I see that there are several technologies to accomplish the task but they are **bound** to the **content type**. XML has XPath or Xpointer, JSON has JSONPath and so on.

The question is: if XML and JSON are two ways of representing structured information (which are almost equivalent), do you know some **high level**, **implementation-independent** notation which is not bound to a specific representation?

**CONSTRAINTS:**

Please consider that I can't go with the plain URL mechanism. I mean, I can't do something like `http://authority/.../zoo/dog`.

Here the *resource* is the `zoo`, I need to traverse its content (treating it as a content).

Just to clarify a little, something like `http://authority/.../zoo#dog` would do the trick because it separates the resource name (what stands before the `#`) from the content name (what stands after the `#`) but I'm not sure whether if using it in this way can be considered standard or not. In addition, the # strategy requires that the resource is annotated with anchor points, which is not desirable for my case.

Comment: Maybe a selector such as `zoo > dog`? (There exists a custom language for JSON called [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org) but it has JSON-specific semantics and therefore uses a non-standard syntax... but then neither is the standard syntax fully applicable to either XML or JSON anyway.)

Comment: JSON and XML are *not* "almost equivalent". Perhaps some specific data you care about is encoded in analogous ways in JSON and XML, but that's because this encoding only uses a trivial subset of both. Take a closer look at XPath, many of its features exist to support XML stuff that doesn't even exist in JSON (e.g. namespaces, attributes).

Comment: Some XML Databases like [BaseX](http://www.basex.org) have support for [reading JSON](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/JSON_Module), which is then queryable using XQuery (being a superset of XPath).

Comment: ok, I accept @delnan stricture. We could discuss about the fact that both two formalisms map on a tree structure, do you agree? If you do, then we're making an abstraction step because we are thinking of the essence beyond the implementation. However, I fear that what I'm looking for is just URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The question is: if XML and JSON are two ways of representing structured information (which are almost equivalent), do you know some high level, implementation-independent notation which is not bound to a specific representation?

Here are a few:

- Resource Description Framework(RDF)
- Abstract Syntax Notation(ASN.1)
- Property List(PList)
- Registry Files(Reg)
- OData
- Microdata
- EXI
- Canonical S-Expressions(Canonical S-expr)

**References**

- [Media Types Issues for Text RDF Formats](http://www.w3.org/2008/01/rdf-media-types)
- [RDF Serializations](http://www.w3.org/wiki/RdfSyntax)
- [RDF Translator](http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/)
- [Abstract Syntax Notation One (ASN.1) Recommendations](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/)
- [Overview of the JSON Encoding Rules (JSON/ER): a
  set of encoding rules for ASN.1](http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/asn1-papers/Overview%20of%20JSON%20ER.pdf)
- [Darwin Plist Man Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html)
- [Property List Representations](http://readtiger.com/wkp/en/Property_list)
- [Introduction to Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Old-Style ASCII Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html)
- [Property List XML Tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPropertyLists/Articles/XMLTags.html)
- [Distributing Registry Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727154.aspx)
- [How to Create a Brand New Registry Hive](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sergey_babkins_blog/archive/2014/11/10/how-to-create-a-brand-new-registry-hive.aspx)
- [Registering COM Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683954)
- [How to: Create a Registry Key and Set Its Value in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy6azwf7.aspx)
- [Create and implement an XPCOM component for the Firefox browser](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-xpcomfirefox/index.html)
- [Distributing Registry Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727154.aspx)
- [JSON/XML-RPC Client and Server](https://code.google.com/p/json-xml-rpc/wiki/DocumentationForJavaScript)
- [Concise Binary Object Representation (CBOR)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7049)
- [Adjacency List — NetworkX 1.10 documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.adjlist.html)
- [jsonGRDDL: JSON/XML GRDDL Client and Server](http://buzzword.org.uk/2008/jsonGRDDL/spec#abstract)
- [Linked Data API: Formatting Graphs](http://code.google.com/p/linked-data-api/wiki/API_Formatting_Graphs)
- [OData and Schema.org (pdf)](https://www.w3.org/wiki/images/4/43/ODataVocabulariesandSchemaorg.docx.pdf)
- [Microdata: Extracting JSON](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#extracting-json)
- [W3C Wiki: WebSchemas](https://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas)
- [Microdata to RDF: Second Edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata-rdf/)
- [Microdata for Dummies: Extracting Semantic Annotations](http://getschema.org/index.php/Main_Page)
- [EXI for JSON](https://www.w3.org/TR/exi-for-json/)
- [JSONPointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901)/[XPointer](http://www.w3.org/TR/xptr/)
- [Certificate Library Services API](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9629299/2_chap05.htm)
- [US6779120: Declarative language for specifying a security policy](http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US6779120)
- [XML Signature Syntax and Processing Version 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/)
- [oEmbed makes embedding third party videos and images a breeze](http://ajaxian.com/archives/oembed-makes-embedding-third-party-videos-and-images-a-breeze)